# Declare dictionary [String:AnyObject] with overflowing Integers

Tags: ios, swift, integer-overflow

In one of my Unit tests I need to declare a `[String:AnyObject]` which contains sometimes big (>32 bits) Integer values.

```
[
   ["timestamp": 1460793600000,"expectedState": "close"],
   ["timestamp": 1460822400000,"expectedState": "open"]
]
```

Writing the integers as literals triggers the following error :

> Integer literal overflows when stored into 'Int' error

I know I could write it with `NSNumbers`

```
[
   ["timestamp": NSNumber(longLong:1460793600000),"expectedState": "close"],
   ["timestamp": NSNumber(longLong:1460822400000),"expectedState": "open"]
]
```

But that doesn't match the data I'm expecting (It's a `JSON` array stored in a Transformatable Core Data property).

The purpose of my test is to ensure that I'm handling correctly 64 bits values on a 32bits device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I feel a bit dumb on this.

The numbers returned by my `NSManagedObject`'s array are of type `__NSCFNumber` so they are a NSNumber.

Yet, I'm still figuring out how I could write a test to ensure It handles 64 bits values without having to running the unit test on a 32bits device.

Comment: If you avoid types which have a different length on 32 and 64 bit machines (like `Int`  / `NSInteger`) you are safe. For primitives use types with a fixed length (like `Int64`).